# Integration and Limit for sine

Tags: integration, derivatives

Fix any $a$ in $(0, \pi)$. For each $k$ in $\mathbb{N}$ define the sequence $s_{k}=\int_{a}^{\pi}(\sin k x) / k x d x$. Prove that
$\lim _{k \rightarrow \infty} s_{k}=0$

In order to tackle such exercises, we have to find some $\delta$ for each $\epsilon$ in which whenever $k \geq \delta$ holds, then $|s_k| \leq \epsilon$ becomes true. After working with FTC and L'Hopital's rule, all my attempts resulted in vain, wherein the only choice left turned out to be some inequality proceedings. Does anyone have further suggestions on how could be proceeded?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\vert s_k\vert \le \frac{A}{k}$$

Where

$$A =\int_a^\pi \frac{dx}x.$$

So for $\epsilon \gt 0$, just take $\delta =\frac{A}{\epsilon}$.

Comment: It seems that instead of sin function, there could be any bounded function as well, right?

Comment: Any function with a bounded integral I would rather say.